# Firefox warnings

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-1.5

Should I worry about the Firefox warnings regarding jquery 1.5.2, f.x.

```
Warning: reference to undefined property a[d.expando]
Source File: http://localhost:51946/site/backend/script/jquery-1.5.2.min.js
Line: 16
```

or

```
Warning: reference to undefined property f[h]
Source File: http://localhost:51946/site/backend/script/jquery-1.5.2.min.js
Line: 16
```

Comment: Is this while using `jQuery.data()`?..

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the 1.8.0b6 version of firebug fixed the problem for me.